# Use Jquery to auto show Google Maps by scanning Address in a content

Tags: jquery, google-maps

Is their any way to show Google Map by scanning the page content and extracting address form the content and use that address to show map. If you can suggest or their is some jQuery tips than it will be great!

Comment: Can this content be anywhere on the page? Can multiple addresses exist on the page? Is there any specific format that you are expecting?

Comment: Yes the content can be anywhere in the page. No multiple address. No specific format i expect. I was think of this as it can increase any community driven website viewing experience. thanks :)

Comment: If formatting is really required... than how to do the same ?

Answer (score 0):

So, this may not be the best solution, but I would recommend that you leverage the string function, search(). You could do something like this...

```
var myRegExp = /RegEx for Address/;
var result = $("body").text().match(myRegExp);
if(result) {
    // A match was found and is now stored in the result var. Use that to
    // display the map.
}
```

Once you have that result, you can then leverage the [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/) to display the location on your map.

I'll leave it as an exercise for you to come up with the appropriate RegEx (namely because, depending on what locale you are working in, the regular expressions for postal addresses can be very different).

Comment: Hey JasCav thaks for the such awesome reply, 
Yes... your RegEx for the Postal address will be a tough part i suppose... let me search over the internet for that, if you have some idea for the same please provide... Apart for that, thank you very much for the reply.

Comment: @TamalDey - No problem. Happy to help. If this answer did help you, I would ask that you please vote it up (the up arrow next to the question). If it solved your problem, also click the green check mark. This gives back to the users who spent time helping you. (I'll provide some RegEx suggestions when I get a moment.)

Comment: I have low reputation here to i cant vote but i will soon. Thanks, please look forward where ever you get time for Regular Expressions....

Comment: @TamalDey - No problem. However, you should be able to accept answers and upvote on your own questions. As far as a regular expression for addresses, I would recommend a Google search. Parsing a mailing address is no simple task.